# Optimization of Curve fitting

Tags: fitting

I have a set of data:

```
{{0°, 222597.}, {10°, 215256.}, {20°, 205889.}, {30°, 190917.}, 
{40°, 173117.}, {50°, 154249.}, {60°, 138540.}, {70°, 125409.}, 
{80°, 116973.}, {90°, 112937.}}
```

and I believe it is of the form `a*cos(x+b)+c`, where `a`, `b`, and `c` are undetermined coefficients.

As a result I use `FindFit` to determine the three coefficients.

```
data = {{0°, 222597.}, {10°, 215256.}, {20°, 205889.}, {30°, 190917.}, 
       {40°, 173117.}, {50°, 154249.}, {60°, 138540.}, {70°, 125409.}, 
       {80°, 116973.}, {90°, 112937.}};

intensityList = data[[All, 2]];

model = a Cos[b + 10°*x]^2 + c;

fittingParameter = FindFit[intensityList, {model}, {a, b, c}, x];

p2 = Plot[{a Cos[b+x]^2 + c} /. fittingParameter, {x, -0.1, 3.2}];
p1 = ListPlot[data];
Show[p1, p2]
```

And I get a curve which is not well-fitted as expected.

[image]

However, if I eliminate the fitted `b` coefficient, the curve is much more well-fitted.

[image]

Usually when there are more manipulable coefficients, the better the curve-fitting. I hazard a guess that constraints on `b` coefficient is necessary. How should I do so that I can obtain the more accurate `a`, `b`, `c` coefficients?

Comment: try also `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data,  a Cos[b + 10 \[Degree]*x]^2 + c, {a, b, c}, x]; p3 = Plot[nlm[x], {x, -0.1, 3.2}];Show[p1, p3]`?

Comment: @kglr: Without x-factor `10 \[Degree]`  your solution is straightforward!

Comment: Can the a, b, c coefficients be extracted from NonlinearModelFit?

Comment: @chika:  `NonlinearModelFit` can return the estimates of the coefficients:  `nlm["BestFitParameters"]` (as stated in the online help).  `NonlinearModelFit` can provide much more than `FindFit` so I would avoid using `FindFit`.  I have no idea why one would even want to use the more limited `FindFit` (unless there's less overhead and it's speedier if for some strange reason one doesn't need goodness-of-fit summaries).  In fact, I think I'll ask that question.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is you are changing the horizontal axis a few times. Try

```
data = {{0 °, 222597.}, {10 °, 215256.}, {20 °, 205889.},
    {30 °, 190917.}, {40 °, 173117.}, {50 °, 154249.}, 
    {60 °, 138540.}, {70 °, 125409.}, {80 °, 116973.}, {90 °, 112937.}};
model = a Cos[b + x]^2 + c;
fittingParameter = FindFit[data, {model}, {a, b, c}, x]
p2 = Plot[model /. fittingParameter, {x, 0, 90 °}];
p1 = ListPlot[data];
Show[p1, p2]
```

Note: there is no need to extract the "y values" as you did with `intensityList = data[[All, 2]]` and therefore there is no need to try to re-scale the horizontal axis as you did with the factor 10 in `model = a Cos[b + 10°*x]^2 + c`.

From the documentation of [FindFit](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html):

> The data can have the form {{x1,y1,…,f1},{x2,y2,…,f2},…}, where the number of coordinates x, y, … is equal to the number of variables in the list vars.